# Using quotes within a javascript array and getting the result verbatim

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have an array that looks like:

```
var typeArray = [
"'<span class="class">Text</span>'",
"test",
]
```

and im calling the array in code that looks like this:

```
<script> 
            var elem = document.getElementById("pHolderGen1"); 
            var num = 151; 

            for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                var d = document.createElement('div');
                    d.setAttribute('class', 'pfl');
                    d.innerHTML =  '<p>'  
                    + typeArray[i-1] +  
                    '</p>';
                    elem.appendChild(d);
            }
</script>
```

Now I know there  is an issue in the array with my use of quotes around class; however when I change it to:

```
var typeArray = [
    "'<span class="/"grass"/">Grass</span>'",
    "test",
]
```

as an attempt to get rid of the qoute issue I'm having all it displays is "NaN."
When I actually run the code I want it to produce (in html):

```
<p><span class="class">Text</span></p>
```

So in short I'm looking for a way to fix this and I also want to know why it does this.

Comment: The real question is why on earth you didn't just do `'<span class="grass">Grass</span>'`, why do you need an extra set of quotes ?

Comment: and even then, escape character is \  not  /

Comment: Or even better, as you seem to know about `createElement`, why not create actual elements instead of using strings.,

Comment: I'm using s tring because this is a simplified version of the code and this way is hella quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `"'<span class="class">Text</span>'"` to `"<span class='class'>Text</span>"`